# Custom Pagination not displaying for custom post types page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have used a code snippet to build custom pagination:

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'procare_paging_nav' ) ) :
/**
 * Display navigation to next/previous set of posts when applicable.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function procare_paging_nav() {
    // Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
    if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    $paged        = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
    $query_args   = array();
    $url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );

    if ( isset( $url_parts[1] ) ) {
        wp_parse_str( $url_parts[1], $query_args );
    }

    $pagenum_link = remove_query_arg( array_keys( $query_args ), $pagenum_link );
    $pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $pagenum_link ) . '%_%';

    $format  = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
    $format .= $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( 'page/%#%', 'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

    // Set up paginated links.
    $links = paginate_links( array(
        'base'     => $pagenum_link,
        'format'   => $format,
        'total'    => $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages,
        'current'  => $paged,
        'mid_size' => 2,
        'add_args' => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
        'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        'next_text' => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        'type'      => 'list',
    ) );

    if ( $links ) :

    ?>
    <nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
        <?php echo $links; ?>
    </nav><!-- .navigation -->
    <?php
    endif;
}
endif;
?>
```

I used the function for blog posts and the pagination appeared for home.php page.
But the pagination is not appearing on my custom post types page.
I have created custom post type called 'ervaringen'.

And in my page-ervaringen.php:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$partnersLoop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'ervaringen', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged ) ); 

while( $partnersLoop->have_posts() ): $partnersLoop->the_post();        
?>

<div class="post press-photo">
        <div class="image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div><!-- image -->
        <div class="content">
            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div><!-- content -->
</div><!-- .press-photo -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php procare_paging_nav(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

So, if anyone can help me by telling what I am doing wrong that I am missing the pagination on my custom post page.

What other solutions I have tried and didn't work for me:

Changing the function to pass custom query as argument instead of using global query.

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists( 'procare_paging_nav' ) ) :

function procare_paging_nav($partnersLoop) {


    // Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
    if ( $partnersLoop->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    $paged        = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) 

    $pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
    $query_args   = array();
    $url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );

    if ( isset( $url_parts[1] ) ) {
        wp_parse_str( $url_parts[1], $query_args );
    }

    $pagenum_link = remove_query_arg( array_keys( $query_args ), $pagenum_link );
    $pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $pagenum_link ) . '%_%';

    $format  = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
    $format .= $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( 'page/%#%', 'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

    // Set up paginated links.
    $links = paginate_links( array(
        'base'     => $pagenum_link,
        'format'   => $format,
        'total'    => $partnersLoop->max_num_pages,
        'current'  => $paged,
        'mid_size' => 2,
        'add_args' => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
        'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        'next_text' => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        'type'      => 'list',
    ) );

    if ( $links ) :

    ?>
    <nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
        <?php echo $links; ?>
    </nav><!-- .navigation -->
    <?php
    endif;
}
endif;
?>
```

and in page-ervaringen.php

```
procare_paging_nav($partnersLoop);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: change 'posts_per_page' => to -1 and try

Comment: Already did. But that didn't solve and displayed all the posts on same page.

Comment: Side note (aka not the fix you're looking for) You don't need to use `__()` around your prev_text/next_text arguments since you're just passing markup for icons instead of translatable text.

Comment: Have you verified that you're getting the expected values to pass to 'total' and 'current'?

Comment: thanks for the note on removing __(). Removed them from the code.

Comment: @LucasBonner.  So, I did the test just now. and got 0 when echoing $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages.

And got 1 when echoing $paged.

So, the function is executing the return since I am getting a zero for $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages. What should I do next?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solved it by passing custom query rather than using global query.

Comment: Awesome, glad you go it figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to to pass custom query as argument instead of using global query.

I tried this solution earlier too but didn't get the result as I didn't replace the global query in the link section with the custom ones.

Solved the problem after getting a bit of help from @lucas

Thanks.

Here is the solution. If it might help someone in the future.

In page-ervaringen.php

```
procare_paging_nav($partnersLoop);
```

Custom pagination function:

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'procare_paging_nav' ) ) :
/**
 * Display navigation to next/previous set of posts when applicable.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function procare_paging_nav($partnersLoop) {


    // Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
    if ( $partnersLoop->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    $paged        = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;


    $pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
    $query_args   = array();
    $url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );

    if ( isset( $url_parts[1] ) ) {
        wp_parse_str( $url_parts[1], $query_args );
    }

    $pagenum_link = remove_query_arg( array_keys( $query_args ), $pagenum_link );
    $pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $pagenum_link ) . '%_%';

    $format  = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
    $format .= $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( 'page/%#%', 'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

    // Set up paginated links.
    $links = paginate_links( array(
        'base'     => $pagenum_link,
        'format'   => $format,
        'total'    => $partnersLoop->max_num_pages,
        'current'  => $paged,
        'mid_size' => 2,
        'add_args' => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
        'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        'next_text' => '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        'type'      => 'list',
    ) );

    if ( $links ) :

    ?>
    <nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
        <?php echo $links; ?>
    </nav><!-- .navigation -->
    <?php
    endif;
}
endif;
?>
```